# Making a popup (which is a DIV containing a panel - consist of textbox and a button) to fit (float) within (map) a specific DIV only

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, arcgis-js-api

The HTML for the popup is:

```
<div id="commentBox" class="commentBox">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
       <input type="text" value="" id="annotationText" />
       <button type="button" ng-click="setComment()">OK</button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.commentBox {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    left: 72px;
    top: 58px; 
    display:none;
}

#commentBox:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: '';
}

#commentBox:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}
```

The commentBox:after and commentBox:before are the small arrow-tip and it's shadow on top-right corner of commentBox.

Issue: when I click on map on extreme right-side the popup-div shows outside of the main Map Div. Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

When clicked somewhere else:

[image]

How do I make this DIV (popup) to display within the limits of MAP DIV when clicked extreme right on MAP?

Comment: does the map occupy whole page?

Comment: @Shashank
No it does not. It is part of the whole page.
 Below is the div which contain "map" div(this "accountMapSettings" div is part of whole page).
<div ng-if="accountMapSettings" class="col-md-12 assetMapBg projectPadding menuIsNotExpand ng-scope" ng-class="mapExpand(isMapExpand)">

<div id="map" class="map" data-basemap="streets" data-zoom="13" data-scale="72223.819286" data-loaded="" _dijitmenudijit_menu_0="1">

Comment: accountMapSettings div occupies the whole page correct?
is it okay if the popup is at the middle of this div?

Comment: @Shashank, accountMapSettings DIV is a part of whole page(page contains other DIVs as well) and the map DIV is within accountMapSettings.
The popup should open at the exact position, where the user clicks on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of javascript something like this

```
function onMapClick(event) {
  let comment =  document.getElementById('commentBox');
  let top = event.target.offsetTop + event.target.offsetHeight/2 - comment.offsetHeigth/2;
  let left = event.target.offsetLeft+ event.target.offsetWidth/2 - comment.offsetWidth/2;
  comment.style.left = left+"px";
  comment.style.top = top+"px";
  comment.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

css

```
.commentBox {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Sure, I will give it a try and I will let you know. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I added few of new CSS classes to get this done

```
.commentDiamond {
        background: #F7F7F7;
        display: block;
        height: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 16px;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0.75em #777777;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.75em #777777;
    }

.commentDiamond.topleft {
    left: 5px;
    top: -6px;
}

.commentDiamond.topright {
    right: 5px;
    top: -6px;
}

.commentDiamond.bottomleft {
    left: 5px;
    top: 45px;
}

.commentDiamond.bottomright {
    right: 5px;
    top: 45px;
}
```

And then in JS file checked for the screen point and conditioned asper my requirement and then showed the required CSS classes from above list.

```
if (scrn_pt.x > (mapwidth - $("#commentBox").width() + 10) && scrn_pt.y > (mapHeight - $("#commentBox").height())) {
    $('#commentDiamond').removeClass();
    $('#commentDiamond').addClass("commentDiamond bottomright");
    $("#commentBox").css({
        left: scrn_pt.x - 187 + "px",
        top: scrn_pt.y - 13 + "px"
    });
    $('#commentBox').show();
    $('#annotationText').focus();
} else if (scrn_pt.x > (mapwidth - $("#commentBox").width())) {
    $('#commentDiamond').removeClass();
    $('#commentDiamond').addClass("commentDiamond topright");
    $("#commentBox").css({
        left: scrn_pt.x - 187 + "px",
        top: scrn_pt.y + 60 + "px"
    });
    $('#commentBox').show();
    $('#annotationText').focus();
} else if (scrn_pt.y > (mapHeight - $("#commentBox").height())) {
    $('#commentDiamond').removeClass();
    $('#commentDiamond').addClass("commentDiamond bottomleft");
    $("#commentBox").css({
        left: scrn_pt.x + 1 + "px",
        top: scrn_pt.y - 13 + "px"
    });
    $('#commentBox').show();
    $('#annotationText').focus();
} else {
    $('#commentDiamond').removeClass();
    $('#commentDiamond').addClass("commentDiamond topleft");
    $("#commentBox").css({
        left: scrn_pt.x + 1 + "px",
        top: scrn_pt.y + 60 + "px"
    });
    $('#commentBox').show();
    $('#annotationText').focus();
}
```

Now the popup look like these:
[image]
[image]
[image]